# Dynamics 365 change tracking many to many relationship

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-portals

Has anyone tried using change tracking for many to many relationships? Since change tracking is enabled at the entity level, I'm not sure how to set it up (if it's possible). I'm using some m:m relationships in the portal and would like the data to be properly reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, like you said, change tracking has to be enabled in entity level and Native many to many relationship created intersect entity is not exposed to customize. So no way to do that.

If it’s Manual many to many relationship (1:N from either side) then you get an intersect entity to enable change tracking.

**Edit**:

Noticed that the native N:N relationship also creates a table in database (which is not visible anywhere) & getting synced using Data Export Service without need to enable “change tracking”.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented on my local environment.

I noticed that the tracking is enabled in the in-between entity only if both entities at the extremes of the relationship have tracking active too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).